# A question about inversion in affirmative sentences

Tags: adverbs, inversion

Which is correct?

"In fact it is rather simple, just a story of two children. But in this apparent simplicity **the book delivers** a wonderful exposition of so great memories, ideas and dreams.

or,

"In fact it is rather simple, just a story of two children. But in this apparent simplicity **does the book deliver** a wonderful exposition of so great memories, ideas and dreams."

Comment: Can you please finish the sentences? With the fragments you provided, I'm not able to tell if it is a question or what the context is.

Comment: I edited the sentences.

Answer (score 1):

> But in this apparent simplicity, the book delivers a wonderful exposition of so many great memories, ideas, and dreams.
>
> But in this apparent simplicity, the book does deliver a wonderful exposition of so many great memories, ideas, and dreams.

These would be proper ways to write it, unless it was a question, in which case you'd write:

> In this apparent simplicity, does the book deliver a wonderful exposition of so many great memories, ideas, and dreams?

Though you could argue that **does the book** is just an inversion of **the book does**, I still think that it's not very natural to write it that way at all. I usually only see *does* used before the subject if you are asking a question. Example:

> **Does the book read nicely?**

Vs.

> **The book does read nicely.**

Though this isn't always a rule, it's generally considered to be more grammatical in my experience.

Comment: Thanks. Inversion in affirmative sentences generally (but far from always) happens with negative adverbial phrases I am assuming?

Comment: That's right, @user7945753. It's a rather literary stylistic effect, but only with a negative-polarity adverbial phrase do you ever find it. (Do you see what I did there?). You could make your sentence grammatical by adding "only" after "but" - but that would change the meaning slightly.

Answer (score 0):

The "does" in the second sentence is sort of archaic and a bit poetic. There are places and times where it wouldn't have been incorrect. But today it is, at best, unclear.